# How can I make a colored google maps, like this one?

Tags: google-maps, embed, footer

I saw a google maps, and I can make this only black-and-white, but this one is different.

How can I embed that with these colors?

You can find the colored google maps here(bottom of the page): http://market.hu/hu/

Answer (score 1):

you need api key

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD-EHwgYHiDPCXYj7YIrVtW0IIC9zJQKfk"></script>
        <script>
            function initialize() {
                var myLatLng = {lat: 47.559377, lng: 19.038524};

                var mapProp = {
                    center: myLatLng,
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    styles: [{"featureType": "all", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [{"saturation": 36}, {"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 40}]}, {"featureType": "all", "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [{"visibility": "on"}, {"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 16}]}, {"featureType": "all", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 20}]}, {"featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [{"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 17}, {"weight": 1.2}]}, {"featureType": "landscape", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 20}]}, {"featureType": "poi", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 21}]}, {"featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 17}]}, {"featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [{"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 29}, {"weight": 0.2}]}, {"featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 18}]}, {"featureType": "road.local", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 16}]}, {"featureType": "transit", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 19}]}, {"featureType": "water", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#000000"}, {"lightness": 17}]}]
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: myLatLng,
                    title: 'Bojtár u. 49-59',
                    labelContent: 'Bojtár u. 49-59'
                });

            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:372px;height:263px;"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try and give feedback :)

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. I forgot to mention that it's a wordpress site.